# Why OnHScrollChange is not fired in stringgrid in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Why OnHScrollChange is not fired in stringgrid  in Firemonkey? How should i catch the scrolling event in Stringgrid?

Answer (score 0):

`OnHScrollChange` is fired when you scroll with the scrollbar thumbgrip or its buttons. It is however not fired by changing the selection with the left and right arrow keys, even if that would result in the thumbgrip of the scrollbar being moved.

If your question is about the latter situation, I kind of agree with you that it should trigger the `OnHScrollChange`, but then again, I have no idea of any design decisions. You may want to enter a report at Embarcadero's Quality Portal and see how they respond.

Another possibility is to use the `OnViewportPositionChange` event instead which fires however the viewport position changes. The caveat is that it fires also on vertical scrolling. If this is ok for you then that is your solution.